# I'm working with a color conversion in python and get 'False' back

Tags: python

I'm trying to convert from XYZ to RGB using the equations from [here](https://github.com/PhilipsHue/PhilipsHueSDK-iOS-OSX/blob/master/ApplicationDesignNotes/RGB%20to%20xy%20Color%20conversion.md).

The original code is in C, which I understand much better than python.  I've tried to convert it and
I think I'm close to having it, but it gives me back 'False, False, False'.  Can anyone see why?

```
x=0.1
y=0.8
z = 1.0 - x - y
Y = 255
X = (Y / y) * x
Z = (Y / y) * z

r = X * 1.612 - Y * 0.203
g = -X * 0.509 + Y * 1.412 +Z * 0.066
b = X * 0.026 - Y * 0.026 - Y * 0.072 + Z * 0.962

r = r <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * r else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
g = g <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * g else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
b = b <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * b else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055

print r,g,b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last three lines before the print to the following:

```
r = 12.92 * r if r <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
g = 12.92 * g if g <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
b = 12.92 * b if b <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
```

I think you probably translated a ternary like `<condition> ? <true value> : <false value>` in C to `<condition> if <true value> else <false-value>` in Python, but ternary in Python uses the following structure:

```
<true value> if <condition> else <false value>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have your conditions and values switched. The structure of the ternary operator in python is:

```
trueOption if condition else falseOption
```

Whereas your code appears to be using

```
condition if trueOption else falseOption
```

Which is the structure used by C/C++.

This means that the wrong values are being used in the expression, since they are in the wrong order.

Change

```
r = r <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * r else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
g = g <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * g else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
b = b <= 0.0031308 if 12.92 * b else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
```

to

```
r = 12.92 * r if r <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(r, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
g = 12.92 * g if g <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(g, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
b = 12.92 * b if b <= 0.0031308 else (1.0 + 0.055) * pow(b, (1.0 / 2.4)) - 0.055
```

Your mathematical expressions always evaluate to `True`, while the conditionals are evaluating to `False`.